# NGINX, accept or reject end-user certificates by issuing CA

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have one root CA and ten sub-CA-s. In mu NGINX configuration I want to accept authentication requests for certificates issued by two sub-CA-s and reject all requests for certificates issued by any other sub-CA (including external CA-s). Basically, I want to trust only two subordinate authorities for authentication in NGINX.

How is it possible?

Comment: See [NGinx SSL certificate authentication signed by intermediate CA (chain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431528/nginx-ssl-certificate-authentication-signed-by-intermediate-ca-chain).

Comment: The answer suggested by @SteffenUllrich has drawbacks as the server will send the Root certificate to the client.  Clients (such as your browser) will then present you with all client certificates signed by CAs signed by that Root - that is, potentially ten client certification paths instead of the two which you trust for authentication.  The correct way to do this is to stand up a new Root CA for client authentication and add only that Root CA to Nginx's configuration.

Comment: if ($ssl_client_i_dn != "/C=PL/CN=IntermediateCA1/emailAddress=cert@asdf.com") {
        return 403;
    } - I think it should work because all requests from other intermediate CA-s will be rejected. My problem is, I cannot get it work. I can query "openssl x509 -noout -in CLIENTCERTNAME -issuer" and get the answer, but it is not recognized :( So, how can I clarify how exactly should the value be set in my expression? Even more I like expression if ($ssl_client_i_dn !~* "CN=<intermediary CN>") {     return 403;   }, but it doesn't work either. How to troubleshoot? Thanks!

Comment: if ($ssl_client_i_dn != - it works well. I found exact value after enabled debug error loging. Thanks.